# CakePHP route keeps going back to /

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to connect /admin/ to a static page 'admin.ctp'.

I copied the pages controller for modification and copied the display function to admin_display. I also tried creating an admin_index function without parameters. My route looks like this at this moment:

```
Router::connect('/admin/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin'));
```

my admin_index function looks like this:

```
    function admin_index() {
        $page = 'admin';
        $subpage = null;
        $title_for_layout = 'Admin';
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));
        $this->render('/admin');
    }
```

I put admin.ctp in /views/pages/ and in /views/pages/admin/

Anyway. When I go to /admin/ it redirects me to /. But when I delete admin_index, it complains that the function does not exist, so I does look for it.

Help?

edit: Big correction, all my admin urls go back to /
edit2: resolved it, something with appcontroller :$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create admin_index.ctp file in /views/pages/.

Remove `$this->render('/admin');` from the `admin_index` function. (If you wanted to use `admin.ctp`, I think all you would have to do is to remove the `/` from the argument). There's no reason to render `admin.ctp` for `admin_index`, since it's natural for cake to render `admin_index.ctp` for `admin_index` function. You just don't gain anything by not doing that the cake way.

If it doesn't work, try

```
Router::connect('/admin/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
```

If you want to route `/admin/*action*` requests to pages controllers admin_*action* function, then add this line to routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/admin/:action/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Router::connect('/admin/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin')); would work with the standard pages controller